# "first applied to" - June 12th 1799 Letter by John Marshall

Tags: meaning-in-context

> I do not immediately recollect any others among the old officers whom I coud name for so high an office as the command of a regiment. I am aware that those I have mentiond cannot, shoud you on further enquiry approve of them, be all appointed, but I have namd them because it is possible that **those first applied to** may be disinclind to enter into the army. ([Source](http://founders.archives.gov/?q=%20Author%3A%22Marshall%2C%20John%22&s=1111311121&sa=&r=20&sr=))

I'd surmise that **those** refers to the old officers named by Marshall. However, could someone please expound on and unravel **first applied to**?

Marshall didn't name any of these aforementioned old officers first? Or is Marshall referring to those officers who made their applications first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marshall is writing to Washington to provide names of people whom he believes might be invited to command a regiment. Some of the invitees may decline, so he is providing more names than strictly necessary.

**Apply to** here is used in much the same sense as one *applies to* a university: it means to make a formal request.

> **apply** *verb*
>   **1** [*no object*] make a formal application or request:
>   *you need to apply to the local authority for a grant*
>
> [[ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/apply)]

Thus Marshall's meaning is "those first **requested** [to join as a senior officer]".